# Git, Behind Proxy and Keep Getting HTTP code = 417

Tags: git, proxy

our company provide internet access for us using proxy, 
but after configured http.proxy, i am keeping get HTTP code 417 
After a little google, i guess it's because the libcurl that git 
use sent the "Expect: 100-continue" header, which the proxy(i guess a 
Squid) does not understand and reply with 417: Expection failed.

I can not change the proxy setting, so below are my questions:

1. can i disable the Expect header of libcurl? 
   i know i can use -H option of curl(the binary), but seems git/ 
   libcurl does not support this option.
2. or how can i get around this problem without do anything with the 
   proxy ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to use Git through the proxy? You could try this:

```
git config --global http.proxy="http://<user>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>"
```

For example,

```
git config --global http.proxy="http://jonathan:Password1@webproxy:8090"
```

Then, when performing a `git clone` or setting up a `git remote`, use `http://` instead of `git://` as the protocol.

Comment: yes, i was using proxy, but my proxy does not support 100-continue header that Git's libcurl send to it. Sorry, it's my first question on StackOverflow, i do not know how to format the text.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about proxying with Squid, but if you only need to pull, could you mirror the git repository with curl or wget to a local folder, and then tell git to use that instead?

Comment: i was pull from github, could you tell me how can i mirror some project from github? For example http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver.git

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, it seems that I could push small changes through (under 1 kb) but when trying it with larger push our proxy server kicked in (which uses Squid probably) and I got following trace as a result:

```
Counting objects: 50, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29/29), 3.47 KiB, done.
Total 29 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 417
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Problem was solved by unsetting all proxy settings from git as:

```
git config --global --unset-all http.proxy # to remove it from the global config
git config --unset-all http.proxy  # to remove it from the local repo config file
```

And adding our (stash git) LAN ip/domain to /etc/hosts as:

```
sudo /etc/hosts
```

Inside that file I added following:

```
192.168.xx.xxx  git.ourcompany.com
```

And boom, problem solved! **(Dont forget to start up new terminal where you try that push.)**